# How can I set the code to become an Auto Filter instead of creating a command button?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, unique, autofilter

I would like to convert this code into an autofilter instead of having a command button. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sign-ons")
    
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("EmployeeID")
    
'Dim Rng As Range
    'Set Rng = WS1.Range("Input_Table") 'Data table in sheet1
'Dim row As Range

'Dim Shift As AutoFilter
    'Set Shift = WS1.Range("B3")

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    
    ws1.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=ws2.Range("B2"), _
    Unique:=True
     
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean a filter that is automatically applied as soon as the workbook is opened?

Comment: @Wito, yes. I tried to substitute the `.AdvancedFilter` with `.AutoFilter` but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a subroutine to run as soon as you open your workbook, without a trigger like `CommandButton` you can do `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`. You need to write the code under `ThisWorkbook` in VBA and not in a module. This will make the code to run as soon as the workbook is opened.

If what you are looking for is to see the filter in the specified range, you can use `.AutoFilter` over the range you desire to apply the filter on. Bear in mind that the filter will only be applied to the specified range.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sign-ons")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("EmployeeID")
        
With ws1
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B1:B" & LastRow).AutoFilter
End With
     
End Sub
```

The code will apply the `.AutoFilter` as soon as the workbook is opened. It will not filter anything since we have not specified the `Criteria` to filter by which you could also add. You could also trigger this code with a `CommandButton` if you rather to do it so.

The result will look similar to this:

[image]